# Impersonation on ToDo Items via X-LConn-RunAs using the IBM Connections REST API

Tags: rest, api, impersonation, ibm-connections

I have successfully posted data to IBM Connections using the X-LConn-RunAs Header in my API calls to create Activity Stream Entries, Blog Posts, Wiki Pages, Forum Entries and File Uploads on behalf of someone else although it is not documented in some of the APIs. The only API that does not seem to support this Header is the Activity API. Here is what I did:

1. I added my technical user to the "trustedExternalApplication" role in the "WidgetContainer" application.
2. I added my technical user to the "admin" role in all other applications.
3. I added the X-LConn-RunAs Header to my api call like this: X-LConn-RunAs: userid=D2A7325-...
4. I made sure the referenced user exists in IBM Connections.
5. I sent my call to: http://myconnections/activities/service/atom2/activity?activityUuid=GH765...

The post is still being created with the technical user as creator instead of the user referenced by X-LConn-RunAs. I tested this against my on premises IBM Connections 5.0 installation as well as IBM Connections Cloud. While all other API calls support this Header the Activities don't.

Did anybody have more luck than myself and figured out how to use it or is there another way to achieve the same result with a different header or some additional information in the message body? I tried to send an `<author>` element but that is being ignored as it says in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

As just heard in an IBM Connect 16 session (you are sitting left of me ;-) ), as of today Impersonation of activity stream and status update data is not possible

Comment: You cannot impersonate a prior event, you can impersonate an event when you distribute it.  https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Distributing_events_ic45&content=pdcontent His question referred to the Activities API, not the status API.  You may be confusing a discussion on Connections Cloud capabilities vs on-premises.